# Time date does not match format

Tags: python, selenium, datetime, strptime

I have HTML table with 5 columns. In the third column are links and in the fifth column is a date.

Now I want to write a code which checks if the date is within the next 4 weeks and if yes, then click on the link.
But if I run my code I get this error:

> time data [selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="5395379b492ea99d3df3ffaf80718908", element="0.7086675347389584-2")] does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

This is my code:

```
# Set the Date
start = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
now = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d')
date_in_four_weeks = now + datetime.timedelta(days=28)

print start
print now
print date_in_four_weeks

#Clickpath through the table
td_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("css_selector"))
for td in td_list:
    date_list = []
    date = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('time')
for d in date:
    date_list.append(d.text)
    print d.get_attribute('datetime')
    print date_list
for i in range(project_time.days + 1):
    print(now + timedelta(days=i))
    date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y-%m-%d')
    if date_list <= now + timedelta(days=i):
        linkList = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("css_selector")
        for i in range(0,len(linkList)):
            links = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('SOLI')
            links[i].click()
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file("SeeWhatWeHaveHere_%s.png" % (a))
    else:
        print " NAAAH"
```

And this is the part of the HTML table where the date is:

```
<td class="customfield_10090">
    <span title="31.08.17">
        <time datetime="2017-08-31">31.08.17</time>
    </span>
</td>
```

I'm new to Python so I don't know how to fix this problem.

Please Help. Thanks :)

Full output:

```
2017-11-24
2017-11-24 00:00:00
2017-12-22 00:00:00
2017-08-31
[u'31.08.17']
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "comment.py", line 52, in <module>
 date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y-%m-%d')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
 (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data [selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="5395379b492ea99d3df3ffaf80718908", element="0.7086675347389584-2")] does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Comment: The full output from your script could help

Comment: I just add it :)